# Is it possible to remove a particular app in chooser while opening a URL?

Tags: android, android-intent

My own app contains an intent filter which accepts a URL of "https:www.xyz.com"

While opening a particular URL from my own app, for example "https:www.xyz.com/signup",
it gives an option of my app also in chooser, but for this particular URL, I want to open it in browser only.

Please suggest me a proper way exclude my own app from default chooser list of android.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https:www.xyz.com/signup"));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Open with"));
```

Comment: Perhaps your `<intent-filter>` needs a more specific URL, rather than everything in your domain.

Comment: but I need to exclude only a particular URL only i.e. "https:www.xyz.com/signup". Is there any way to modify intent filter for particular URL ?

Answer (score 0):

> but I need to exclude only a particular URL only i.e. "https:www.xyz.com/signup".

That is not possible. The URLs expressed in `<data>` elements in an `<intent-filter>` are a whitelist, not a blacklist or a combination. If you advertise that you support all URLs, you support all URLs, not all URLs minus one.

Hence, you need more constrained `<intent-filter>` elements that limit your URLs to those that you want to support, not all URLs within your domain.

Comment: can we work around with Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS to handle this situation ?

Comment: @SuneetAgrawal: You are not the only one who causes the chooser to appear. Anything else that does an `ACTION_VIEW` on your `signup` URL will encounter the same problem. You need to fix it for all scenarios.